# How to send Jquery datatable data to servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I want to send Jquery datatable to servlet. below is the code.

Jquery in JSP

```
var table2 =  $('#itemtable').DataTable( {
            columns: [
                { data: "p_no"},
                { data: "p_date"},
                { data: "s_id"},
                { data: "it_id" },
                { data: "it_name" },
                { data: "it_type" },
                { data: "it_uni_price" },
                { data: "it_qty" },
                { data: "it_tot_price" }

            ],
            order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
            bProcessing: true,
            bSort: true,
            bJQueryUI: true,
            bLengthChange: true,
            bPaginationType: "two_button"

        } );
```

Ajax request on Save button as below

```
 var oTable = $("#table2").dataTable();
 updateDatabase(oTable.fnGetData());
```

And the updateDatabase() as below

```
function updateDatabase(dataTable) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ERP/Purchase",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data:{dataTable: dataTable},
    success: function(html){
    //success
    }
    });
    }
```

How do I get my datatable data to my servlet?

Comment: New to Jquery. I have JSP page with datatable , Need to send datatabe values to servlet, Please help. search a lot on net but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Is the AJAX call hitting the Servlet? What does your Servlet look like?

Comment: you are doing it right. request.getParameter('dataTable') in servlet should get hold of this data

Comment: public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("application/json");
 
  System.out.println(request.getParameter("dataTable"));}

Comment: on consol I have got null only.

Comment: the ajax post should will need a content type. Add this to the ajax call "contentType": "application/json"